# Excel range Format not rendered as expected (conversion issue)

Tags: excel, ado, vba

The context : I have a sheet called "ForUser" with first row defining headers, following row corresponding to data. I have a second sheet called "ForBuffer" to retreive data from a data base.

[image]

Each column in "ForUser" is associated with a format, applied dynamically (the format can be set up by the user and changed). In the example below there is a column header with value "Att $" in "ForUser" sheet which format is dollar.

```
    Dim objRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rngDataBuffer As Range
    With Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name()).Sheets("ForBuffer")
        Set rngDataBuffer = .Range("A1")
    End With
    rngDataBuffer.CopyFromRecordset Data:=objRs
```

Data are loaded column by column from a data base and copied to a range using **CopyFromRecordset** with data parameter set to a valid **ADODB.Recordset** into the sheet called "ForBuffer"

```
  Dim rDest As Range
  With Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name()).Sheets("ForBuffer")
      With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
       set rDest= .rows(1).Find( _
          What:="Att $", MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookAt:=xlWhole)
      End With
  End With
```

This buffer is then copied to the "ForUser" sheet in column where "Att $" header is defined. Some cells have a value set some don't.

```
  rngDataBuffer.Copy Destination:=rDest
```

I could have copied data stored in **objRs** directly in rDest (but that not the point) using something like

```
rDest.Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset Data:=objRs
```

Offset(1) is necessary to preserve the first row where there is "Att $" header.

Data are saved as string on the data base side, hence then fall has strings in **rngDataBuffer**

Afterwards I apply the format using something like :

```
 rDest.Offset(1).Resize(rDest.rows.count-1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$USD]"
```

for other types I use (dollar currency, text, percentage, float, integer)

```
                    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
                    .NumberFormat = "@"
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                    .NumberFormat = "0.0"
                    .NumberFormat = "0"
```

I can check that the format is set but not rendered probably because the data have been copied as strings.

[image]

How can convert a range of cells to some 'type' (here I say 'type' because 'format' seems to be just the way it looks). ?

I tried to Copy value 1 from some cell and then PasteSpecial with different options. I can get the expected format rendered but this has the drawback to set a 0 (zero) in cells which had no content (null or empty). A zero cell value or an empty cell has a different meaning in the context of my application. Also this solution does not work to render dates.

I also tried to convert data according to the type. It fails all the time with a very explicit message : Type mismatch (error 13). Value is a string but they in deed can be converted to the expected type. The conversion is applied to a range value (multiple cells)

For date

```
 .Value = CDate(.Value)
```

For numeric "types" (integer, float and currency respectively)

```
.Value = CLgn(.Value)
.Value = CDbl(.Value)
.Value = CCur(.Value)
```

None of this worked.

I came up with something which realy left me quite astonished

```
.Value = .Value
```

What's the heck or should i ask what is the magic behind this. By the way this works for Date, currency and double  not for integer neither for percentage !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but it might help, the following will convert a specified range into Currency (ignoring blank cells):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B13").Style = "Currency"
'set the currency format for a specified range
```

Or to be more specific you could do something like below:

```
Dim rng As Range, c as Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A50") 'set the range to be used

For Each c In rng 'for each cell in the specified range
    If c.Value <> "" Then c.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    'if cell is not blank then format it
Next c
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Dim rng As Range, c as Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A50") 'set the range to be used

For Each c In rng 'for each cell in the specified range
    If c.Value <> "" Then c.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    'if cell is not blank then format it
    c.Value = c.Value
    'force the format into the cell
Next c
```

Comment: what is weird is that the format is as expected but not the way the cell is displayed. Once the format was set and if I enter the cell and press carriage return the good format appears. I made progress by the time doing **.Value = . Value** . It worked but for the integer neither percentage case ! I ll look over what the Style property is for the range Object.

Comment: @pascalsautot I've tested the updated version of my answer and it will force the cell to be shown in the right format, please do try it and let me know if any further issues.

Comment: This is what I came up with. Still lopping over cells for large ranges (1000 x 200 cells) is not an ideal solution. Never the less I d like to understand the logics behind all this and why when a format is set it is not applied. What .value = .value is hiding. In I all languages I have practiced this kind of assignment should not change anything unless the setting of value (even if it does not change) trigger event behind which seems to be the case.  That kind of trick is not documented or my eyes did come to cross over it. As such your help was kind but does not answer my questions.